# How to quickly copy and paste / drag formulas to multiple rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

is there a quicker way to copy paste formulas (drag them down) than what I have below?

It's too slow since I have 450000 rows and about 150 columns.

Any ideas how to make it quicker?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,CurrPeriodCheck!$C:$C,1,0)),""FALSE"",""TRUE"")"
    Range("D2").Formula = "=IF($C2=""TRUE"",SUMIFS(PrevPeriodCheck!$K:$K,PrevPeriodCheck!$C:$C,$A2,PrevPeriodCheck!$O:$O,D$1),0)"
    LCprev = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Range("D2").Copy
    Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(LastRowG, LCprev)).PasteSpecial

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Possibly the usual. `Application.calculation = xlmanual` and `application.screenupdating = false` above your code, then `.... Xlautomatic` and `....true` below your code

Comment: I already included in the code what you suggested and it is still too slow

Comment: Probably should be done in a DB. Have you tried Power Query? Do you actually need the formula or just the result of the formula. If the later then you could optimize by building a lookup table in memory and doing every thing in code.

Comment: It needs to be done in Excel since this is just a part of the macro.

Comment: That's a massive amount of calculation (close to 75M cells), so it seems reasonable that it's going to be slow...  Do you need the formulas to remain in the cells, or will you be replacing them with values?

Comment: How many rows on each sheet?

Comment: 450000 rows and about 150 columns for 3 sheets, and another one with 450000 rows but 2 columns. All sheets will contain formulas. But in the end I just need values.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `.Copy` and `.Paste` if you want speed. `.Copy` writes to the clipboard, and then `.Paste` reads from the clipboard, which are unnecessary steps and can slow things down with large ranges like yours.  You're better off making the formula in R1C1-style notation, and then just directly writing that into each excel cell like `MyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "Formula"`

For your code, your `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` lines should be replaced with

```vb
Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(LastRowG, LCprev)).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(RC3=""TRUE"",SUMIFS(PrevPeriodCheck!C11,PrevPeriodCheck!C3,RC1,PrevPeriodCheck!C15,R1C),0)"
```

Comment: FYI an A1-style format formula will auto-adjust when assigned to a multi-cell range: does not need to be R1C1

Comment: @TimWilliams Thats fanctastic! I never knew!

Comment: @Toddleson thanks for trying, but I'm afraid it does not run faster at all

Comment: It's a good answer even if not a faster solution +1